# How to fix invisible form fields in Firefox while using Adwaita Dark Theme (or any other dark theme)

Tags: firefox, themes, gtk3

I have this issue with some form fields in Firefox and using the `adwaita-dark` theme. In some webpages where the field background is white, you cannot read the text because it is also white.

This question was edited in order to clarify that this kind of wording of the question might help people who are not familiar with what a GTK+ theme. I also thing that the wording will help to get more hits through search engines. If it's still considered a duplicate, I'll accept it.

Comment: I consider the possibility that is a duplicate, @muru, although I think that the wording of my question might help other basic users (almost like me) to find the solution through search engines. Also, the original question is outdated and this one has gone through my own testing.

Comment: If your question is closed as a duplicate, people who search for the terms in your question will still find it - that's actually why we value and keep duplicates

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I used the procedure stated in [this website](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox/Tweaks#Unreadable_input_fields_with_dark_GTK.2B_themes).

> 1. Open `about:config` in the address bar
> 2. Create a new string type preference (right mouse button > New > String) named widget.content.gtk-theme-override
> 3. Set the value to the light theme to use for rendering purposes (e.g. Adwaita)
> 4. Restart Firefox

This forced Firefox to use the light theme instead of the dark one in webpages. I think it might work on some other themes that have this issue while using the `dark` variant.